# Mahout seq2sparse is giving IllegalArgumentException

Tags: hadoop, mahout, illegalargumentexception

[image: Screenshot of error]

I have set MAHOUT_LOCAL=TRUE
I did use the local way of running mahout by using file://path_of_file, still did not work for me );

Answer (score 1):

I looked around for people in a similar situation and this post seems to sum up what you're seeing pretty well: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/java-lang-IllegalArgumentException-java-net-UnknownHostException/td-p/12874

Notice that in the line that says `Tokenizing documents in hdfs://user/hduser/seqoutputdata` the first thing after the `hdfs://` is `user`.

That `user` is being interpreted as a hostname in that path, which is why the `java.net.UnknownHostException` thinks it's looking for a host called user.

Looks like you may be able to include a valid hostname in any path you're passing to Mahout: e.g., `hdfs://host/user/hduser/seqoutputdata`.

Comment: What was the solution?